# Error on when Buy Now is Clicked

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, addtocart, cart-rule

I just want clear this out. I am still a newbie in Magento and this give me a hard time debugging it.

Scenario:
1. I add a product on my cart - good
2. I click the Homepage which open into a new Tab.
3. I add the same product
4. I got "Internal Server Error"

I can't add the same product if the cart page is open on the other tab.
Is this something to to with the Session on the Site? What could be the Possible Solution for This?

****Correct Scenario: The product number should increase and the price****

Comment: It seems there is some condition in code as " Not to add product in cart that is already there."

Comment: If you are getting "Internal Server Error" then try enabling logging, you'll get some idea from there about what exact error your code is facing.

Comment: @Prateek where can I find that one?

Comment: Go to system -> configuration -> developer -> log settings. Set that to yes and see in your /var/log folder. If that is already yes, then simply see the files, there will be details about what exact error you are facing.